# How do you express attraction to someone (like a crush)

Tags: expresiones

How do you say *I have a crush on you/her/him/them* (*you* in its *tú* / *Usted* forms) ?

Comment: Wordreference thanslates _to have a crush on sb_ to _estar encaprichado de alguien_. In Spanish, _capricho_ is frivolous when talking about love, as it is a temporal and fickle feeling.

Answer (score 6):

If informal you could go with *estar por*

> Estoy por ti / Estoy por él o por ella.

You could also use *estar loco por* (or *chiflado*) and *me gusta* the same way you use *crazy for* or *like somebody* in English. Other informal forms would be *estar colado por alguien*

> Estoy *colado* por ti.

You could also say that somebody *te pone* if he or she makes you feel *aroused*

> Esa chica *me pone*. Es guapísima.

Or that you are *prendido de*

> Estoy prendido de esa chica desde que la vi por primera vez.

The way of saying it formally would be saying that you like somebody or you are in love with them or attracted to them.

> Me gustas.
>
> Estoy enamorado de ti.
>
> Me siento atraído por ti.

Comment: si es curioso las diferencias culturales, las cuatro primeras nunca se me hubieran ocurrido. `estoy loco por ti` seria lo normal y coloquial para mi en esos casos sin entrar ya en la forma en que se dice en Cuba. `estoy muerto contigo` lol

Comment: Sí, tendrías que aclarar dónde se usan esas expresiones, porque no son nada universales.

Comment: En España son de lo más comunes. Si ustedes tienen sus propias expresiones podrían editar la respuesta para mejorarla, o publicar una respuesta con las suyas.

Comment: Son expresiones muy _españolas_ en México es raro escucharlas, la menos eso de _estoy pro ti_ o _estoy colado_, se entiende la segunda, pero nadie lo diría. Si alguien _te pone_ se entiende que te excita sexualmente y creo que es otra cosa lo que quieres expresar. Estar _prendido_ de alguien suena bien, pero creo que tampoco es la traducción más precisa.  De las ultimas tres, la última podría ser lo más parecido al _crush_. Estar enamorado es más fuerte, eso sería _to be in love with someone_. El _crush_ es fuerte pero de menor intensidad.

Comment: No es "prendido"  sino "prendado".

Answer (score 3):

In México we say:

For *I have a crush on him/her*:

> Me llama la atención *[name here]*

this is kinda vague, the beginning, your fellings are not much clear, or you don have enough courage to accept it. Like the first thoughts. You can also say:

> Me atrae

but it can be understood as sexual atraccion.

This one, depending on what you're saying means that you like him/her or you just have a crush but again is *I have a crush on him/her*:

> Me gusta *[name here]*

*I have a crush on them*, this is  unclear for me but it would be:

> Me gustan
>
> Me llaman la atención
>
> Me agradan

And the formal and informal thing, I don't thing there's any. If you are saying that to someone you are not going to be *formal* I mean, there are more informal forms of saying that but I think that It's better not to use them. They're not bad but I think that being informal on this has to be very special, an especific context, especific person, specific mutual history, you can realx and say what you want but, again, it is a special way of doing it.

An example, you know a girl, you have been like, "I like you..." "Me too" but only in thoughts. And then you finally have the courage and ou are very close, so you can say [This is an example, it can be very different depending the people]:

> Ya pa que nos andamos con rodeos, te gusto y me gustas, ¡andemos chingao!

Tanslation:

> Let's stop going around, you like me and I like you, ¡Let´s be a couple god damn it!

Ok, kinda hard to translate. I want to add that "Andar" is being girlfriend and boyfriend.

> Mira, Juan y María.
> ¿Andan?
> Sí, hace dos días él se le declaró y ahora son novios.

And, *declararse* is the *Would you like to be my girlfriend?*.

Comment: Nobody here would understand "andan" as "son novios". Here (in spain) the word is " salen" . This is so much an everyday thing that probably will vary a lot between countries. I would love to see more comments with local expressions, as not to miss this kind of things when traveling.

Comment: I would love to say, andemos chingao, to a woman. Shame I am happily married.

Answer (score 2):

Se traduce como `Me gustas`.

Ejemplo:

> Tal vez te sientas incómodo cuando invites a salir a la persona que te gusta. 
>   (You might feel awkward asking your crush for a first date.)
>
> Me gusta una compañera de escuela. 
>   (I have a crush on my classmate.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for

> Me gustas mucho *(informal you)*
>
> Me gusta mucho *(him / her / formal you)*

Here, the *mucho* added at the end actually decreases the intensity of the feeling, making it weaker than *Me gustas*, which you could translate into *I like you*.

Answer (score 1):

To have a crush on someone is way, way different than *me atrae, me gusta, me agrada*, etc. *Estar prendido de* comes much closer to it. It's a form of *enamoramiento* to be sure, but it's more and it's different; it's at once more intense and less reliable than being in love. Being in love is more likely to last than having a crush; and you can be in love without losing your head, whereas having a crush can be quite unrealistic. For example, kids have a crush on their teacher, eleven-year-old girls have a crush on Justin Bieber, I had a crush on Ingrid Bergman a few years ago, never mind that if she were still alive she would have beeen like 100 years old, etc.

Although I'm not a native Spanish speaker, I think it's possible that nothing closer than *estar enamorado* exists, unless *estar prendido* qualifies, though I suspect that the latter is closer to "being taken with". In a sufficiently clarifying context, it should be easy to discern whether an *enamorado* has a crush on someone or is in love with them. If the object of their affection is unavailable to them, then there's no two ways about it, it's a crush. *Un corazonazo irracional, ilógico y poco razonable* might be a good definition, but a real translation would of course have to be much more concise.

[minutes later]

The whole time I was writing the above, I was racking my brain, isn't there some Spanish word for this?  And, you guessed it, almost as soon as I hit the post button it came to me (and it even has an English cognate!). The word is *infatuación*.

From Wikipedia:

Infatuación en algunos textos sobre Psicología alude específicamente a cierto estado emocional caracterizado por el dejarse llevar por una pasión irracional, especialmente por el amor adictivo. La infatuación ocurre normalmente al inicio de una relación amorosa. La misma está caracterizada por: urgencia, intensidad, deseo sexual y/o ansiedad, donde hay una extrema absorción del uno con el otro. Se le asocia comúnmente con la juventud y denota infantilismo. Este uso no es muy común y no figura en la edición de 2001 del diccionario de la Real Academia ni en el Diccionario del español actual de Seco, Andrés y Ramos (1999).

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is from Diego.
And actually I could say "colado" it's probably the best for "crush", becouse you don't love actually, you only have this "like" feelings.

Nobody say it before,its another way to say it too in Spain.
like crush is somewhat..informal, isn´t it? This can be mean "crush" too:

> Estoy colgado de él.

The littleraly translation could be I'm hanging with him/her.

You like that person, but you don't really know him/her so much.

But these words look so informal.(colgado/colado)

I'd say if you  want to actually  say that to your actually crush, say

> "Me siento atraído por ti"

While:

> "Estoy colgado por él/ Estoy colado por él"

would be like more saying to your mates or friends that you like someone you don't know so much.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the kind of situation you want to make.

For example if you want to tell this person you want to have a serious relationship you should use **Quiero ser tu novio** in this case you are saying *I want to be your boyfriend*.

But if you want to keep the thing easy and keep dating you should use **Quisiera que siguiéramos saliendo, para conocernos más** in that case you are saying *I want to date you to keep knowing each other*

Hope it helps you!